# Doctrine querybuilder adding subquery changing aliases

Tags: doctrine, query-builder

in a QueryBuilder i have to add some subquery (that i can get from a Repository) using a foreach loop

```php
/** @var Group $group */
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    // Users query builder
    $qbUsers = $this->userRepository->getRecipientsByCriteriaQueryBuilder($group->getCriteria());
    $qbUsers->andWhere('U.id = R.recipient');
    $parameters = $qbUsers->getParameters();
    // Main query builder 
    $qbDelete->andWhere(
        $qbDelete->expr()->not(
            $qbDelete->expr()->exists(
                $qbUsers->getDQL()
            )
        )
    );
}
```

The problem is that in this case i'll have n-times the same alias and this is forbidden. Is there a way to reach this goal?